# How to load data in Meteor App using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, meteor

**Intro:**

I'm newbie in meteor, I have read the documentation and questions here about this issue but the doubt still persist. **My main problem is** that I cant load data of my MongoDb in client side (what methods to use to load data).

**Example:**

I have a project that has the following folder structure: 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52ApL.png)

In my collections (People.js) I have this:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const People = new Mongo.Collection('people');
```

In the server folder ( main.js ). **PS:** I can't change this file.

```
import { People } from '../collections/people';

Meteor.startup(() => {

const TEST_DATA = [
  {
    something: 'This is a simple example',
  }, ... ]

TEST_DATA.forEach(test => People.insert(test));

}
```

In UI folder (app.jsx)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {People} from '../collections/people';

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Teste </h3>
        { console.log(this.users) }
        { console.log(People.find({}).fetch()) }
        { console.log(Meteor.subscribe('people')) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withTracker(() => {
  return {
    users: People.find({}).fetch(),
  };
})(App);
```

cliente folder (main.jsx):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { App } from '../ui/App';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

**Debug:**

I inspected the database and it's populated. The first console.log show ***undefined*** , the second an array of ***length:0***, the third an object `{stop: ƒ, ready: ƒ, subscriptionId: "mJQHdGxka4xTCX7FZ"}` (I think it's returning this because I'm not using publish () on the server to populate the database)

**What method should I use to obtain this data?**

Answer (score 1):

Change `app.jsx` to

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {People} from '../collections/people';

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.users)
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Teste </h3>
        { this.props.users.map((user) => { return (<div>user.something</div>) }) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withTracker(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('people');
  return {
    users: People.find({}).fetch(),
  };
})(App);
```

I've modified the code a little further in the direction that I would assume you'd want it to go. The core change is it use `this.props.users`. That's where the properties in React components can be found, and where they are places by the function returned by `withTracker`.

This all assumes that you are still using `autopublish` (as meteor does in new projects until you remove it). If you have already removed that package, then you need to add

```js
Meteor.publish('people', () => { 
  return People.find();
});
```

in your server code.